# How to join duplicate column name in joins in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables, one is `Employee` and other one is `Dept`.

The `Employee` table has columns which are `ID`, `Name`, and `DeptId`, and `Dept` table has columns `ID`, `DeptName`.

Now if write a query:

```
Select 
    ID, Name, ID, DeptName
from 
    Employee
Inner Join 
    Dept On Employee.DeptID = Dept.ID
```

I get an error because it doesn't know which `ID` column I mean. How do I uniquely define columns?

Comment: Please check your Dept table, does it have a column ID?

Comment: Yes, Dept table had. Problem has been solved. Actually, I needed to distinguish column in the left table from the column in the right table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just include explicit aliases to distiguish the `ID` column in the `Employee` table from the `ID` column in the `Dept` table.  Actually, it is best practice to *always* refer to a column by an alias when doing a join, so your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT e.ID AS employeeID,
       e.Name,
       e.DeptId,
       d.ID AS deptID,
       d.DeptName
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Dept d
    ON e.DeptID = d.ID
```

Answer (score 7):

Use an Alias

```
Select E.ID   as EmpID
     , E.Name
     , D.ID   as DepID
     , D.DeptName  
 From Employee E
 Inner Join Dept D 
 On E.Employee.DeptID = D.Dept.ID
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the table name as qualifier instead of an alias:

```
Select 
    Employee.ID, Employee.Name, Dept.ID, Dept.DeptName
from 
    Employee
Inner Join 
    Dept On Employee.DeptID = Dept.ID
```